# c# Create datatable based off an existing linq table class

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql, datatable

I was wondering if there is a way to create a datatable based on a linq to sql table class.

I'm already creating these classes as I don't use dbml files and have to manually define my tables.

```
[TABLE(Name = "TableA")]
class TableA
{
[Column] public string Name;
[Column] public string surName;
[Column] public string concatName;
[Column] public int ID;
}
```

Now after I do my linq to sql query, I have to manually define the datatable to write to:

```
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
dt.Columns.Add("Name"), typeof(string));
dt.Columns.Add("Surname"), typeof(string));
dt.Columns.Add("concatName"), typeof(string));
dt.Columns.Add("ID"), typeof(int);
```

How can I skip this?  Is there a way to just create my datatable based off the query result, or the already created class?

I've read many things about CopyToDataTable, but can't seem to swing it.

Comment: This seems fairly simple to do `DataTable table1 = query1.CopyToDataTable();` http://blogs.msdn.com/b/aconrad/archive/2007/09/07/science-project.aspx

Comment: @chris-moutray, Something is wrong in my code so it doesn't allow me to do a copytodatatable.  I know I need to cast my linq to sql query as a derivative of datarow, but when I do IEnumarable<DataRow> I get the error message that I'm missing a cast from <TableA> to <DataRow>.